# XML delete duplicated groups

Tags: javascript, xml

I need to delete some duplicated groups in an XML file and copy it's data to one group with Javascript. I parsed it to JSON with node. Or maybe there is another way? Thanks a ton.

Input

```
  <entry>
   <id>1</id>
   <title>Foo</title>
  </entry>

  <entry>
   <id>1</id>
   <title>bar</title>
  </entry>
```

Output

```
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <title2>bar</title>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you using [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js)!

You can transform your XML to an Object, and then you can freely shape the Object using Javascript methods. After getting things done, you can transform the Object to XML again!

If you're using ES6, it would be even easier by using the [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
 method.

Hope it helped!